# Is the display name meant to be escaped HTML in the 2.0 version of the API?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, api-v2, display-name

The `display_name` field of a user is HTML escaped. See [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/142019?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow) for example.

Is this expected behavior or a bug? The [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mentioned under the Safety section of the [filters documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) that by default all response data can be safely inserted into HTML, which is why the data is pre-escaped in this case. You can try [creating an unsafe filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter#unsafe=true&filter=default) using the `unsafe` parameter to use if you wish to [avoid this conversion](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/142019?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow&filter=HZ97).